# API for Sabre Trip Composer?

Tags: sabre

Does anyone know if there is an API to access the contents of Sabre Trip Composer?  So the agent would add options to trip composer, but rather than them opening up Trip Composer to view them, I'd like to be able to retrieve the options added to Trip Composer.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that product (Sabre Trip Composer), and I could not find it in DevStudio. In Agency eServices I found it as something in Graphical View.

I would recommend you to contact the Sabre Trip Composer support and ask them if they have an API that you can consume.